# What does (expr1, expr2) do on the right side of an assignment?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I recently looked at my old code and I can't figure out what this does, or whether it is valid. The code is something like:

```
map<string, string> map;
map[string1] = ("s", string2);
```

Comment: Two strings separated by a comma walk into a bar. Before the first string gets the chance to order, the barman cuts him short and gets the order from the second string. "I am sorry"  he says to the first one "we are serving `-O3` today and you don't have any side effect". [comma evil laugh]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's an obfuscation. The comma operator evaluates all the arguments from left to right but discards all arguments apart from the final one. The formal type of the entire expression is the type of the final argument.

(Note also that the comma itself is a sequencing point.)

string2 becomes the value in the map, under key string1.

Comment: Thanks for the quik reply. Does this mean that for every operator that accept only one parameter, i can type anyting before a comma and this thing i typed is "not seen"?

Comment: @thrower Basically, yes: `int i = ("something", "discarded", 14.4f, 10);` `i` would be `10`.

Comment: I would at least check that `,` is not overloaded before assuming this.

Comment: @Yakk: Can you overload `operator,`, where the left-hand side is of type `const char[2]`?

Comment: The value of the expression before the comma operator may be discarded, but its side effects are not.  In this case, there is no effect because the expression before the comma operator has no side effects.

Comment: @iins yes?  It depends on thr type of the rhs argument.  It is very rare you cannot overload an operator based on rhs argument.  `=` is the only one that comes to mind.

Comment: @Yakk: The question I meant to ask: Can you overload `operator,`, where both arguments are built-in types? (I don't know, I'm genuinely curious.)

Comment: @Peter absolutely! That's why I'm careful enough to say "it evaluates". Note that the formal type of the entire expression is the type of the final argument.

Comment: @rakete1111 your expression will not compile - see the bit of my answer in parentheses: a const char array cannot be converted to an int.

Comment: @Bathsheba [But it does](https://ideone.com/FA5Wb5). As far as I know, the formal type is only in the ternary operator, it doesn't apply to the comma operator.

Comment: @rakete1111 well you learn something new every day! Thank you.

Comment: @Rakete1111 For extra fun, throw exceptions along the way! http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9545d950832569be

Comment: @sehe That's funny :) Didn't know you could do that.

Comment: Quite odd, an answer that completely ignores the possibility (even though it had been pointed out), that the expression in question could be doing something else altogether, gets upvoted. And accepted. I was under the impression, that the voting system was only broken in the low-traffic categories. Apparently it is broken everywhere.

Answer (score 6):

The expression `"s", string2` uses the built-in<sup>1</sup> [comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator). It has the following semantics:

> In a comma expression `E1, E2`, the expression E1 is evaluated, its result is discarded, and its side effects are completed before evaluation of the expression E2 begins (note that a user-defined operator, cannot guarantee sequencing) (*until C++17*).
>
> The type, value, and value category of the result of the comma expression are exactly the type, value, and value category of the second operand, E2.

In case of your code snippet, it isn't useful at all, and its only purpose is to confuse readers. Since evaluating `"s"` has no side-effects, the code is identical to this:

```
map<string, string> map;
map[string1] = string2;
```

---

<sup>1</sup> *This is assuming that no user-defined `operator,` matching the arguments has been defined. If there is, it can do anything, and the remainder of this answer does not apply. You'd have to look into the source code to find out, what the expression evaluates to.*

Answer (score 4):

This is probably the comma operator, which evaluates everything then discards everything except the right hand side value.

But, if `operator,( char const*, string2 )` is overloaded it could do anything (where `string2` is the type of `string2`).

Look for such overloads.

Note that if `string2` is a `std::string` such overloads may make your program ill formed, no diagostic required.  Won't stop people from doing it.  And it may "work" and still permit `,` to (for example) cause concatination of strings.

Answer (score 1):

Comma is operator, that evaluates arguments from left to right, and has value of most-right element.

For example:

```
int a=2, b=3, c;
c = (a+=b, a*b);
```

So, from left, `a+=b` is evaulated first, which sets `a` to `2+3`, then `a*b` is evaulated, and expression has value of `5*3`, which value is used. So `c` is `15`

Comment: Note that this is well defined behaviour since the comma operator is a sequencing point.